# Неправильно масштабируется текст при просмотре с телефонов

Tags: html, css

На сайте неправильно масштабируется текст при просмотре с телефонов.

Ноутбук:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Телефон:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

От чего зависит масштабирование текста на мобильниках и как исправить подобную ситуацию, чтобы на телефоне была полная копия, но меньший масштаб?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну а что вы хотите? Я посмотрел ваш сайт - там везде фиксированная верстка. Все растояния, размеры шрифтов, и т.п. у вас заданы жестко по пикселям.

Видимо изначально у верстальщика не было задачи сделать сайт одновременно адаптированным как для обычных браузеров, так и для мобильных устройств. Это довольно тяжелая задача, которая значительно увеличила бы сроки и стоимость разработки.

К сожалению, не существует какой-то "магической команды", которая бы автоматически всё переделала дизайн сайта таким образом, что он отображался максимально комфортно в любом браузере, и на любом устройстве.

Всё, что сейчас можно сделать - это полностью переверстать сайт под мобильные устройства, если действительно существует такая нужда. Хотя судя по направлению деятельности и целевой аудитории сайта - я честно говоря сомневаюсь в том, что это оправданно.

Comment: А где вы сайт посмотрели? Пока сайт неопубликован. А там старая версия. Но вы правы, сайт с фиксированной вёрсткой.

Comment: @ВикторПавлов, ну он в гугле достаточно быстро находится по словосочетанию "заказали 130 туй" )) Отличий визуальных не увидел - думал именно его и обсуждаете.